# ES6 javascript inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

Provided the following code:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello, my name is ' + this.name);
    }
    sayHelloAndBy() {
        this.sayHello();
        console.log('Bye');
    }

}
class Student extends Person {
    constructor(name, grade) {
        super(name);
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    sayHello() {
        console.log(`Hi, I'm a studend and my name is ` + this.name);
    }
}


let b = new Student("Some guy", 5);

b.sayHelloAndBy();
```

I would like to figure out a way of calling `sayHello` as defined in `Person` and not in `Student`. Is it possible ?

In php there is the `self::` which allows one to do this, but I'm not sure if JS has a similar concept.

Comment: Depends from where you want to call it. So, where do you want to call Person’s sayHello method ?

Comment: You can use `super` in methods to refer to an overridden parent method.

Comment: `Person.prototype.sayHello.call(this)`

Comment: `super. sayHello ` would be the one that you are looking for

Comment: @Ryan That would change the context inside sayHello. this would point the child not the parent inside of sayHello.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: An instance of `Student` is an instance of `Person`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to the version of `sayHello` defined in `Person` through `Person`’s prototype property and call it with the requisite `this` using [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
sayHelloAndBye() {
    Person.prototype.sayHello.call(this);
    console.log('Bye');
}
```

Runnable:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello, my name is ' + this.name);
    }
    
    sayHelloAndBye() {
        Person.prototype.sayHello.call(this);
        console.log('Bye');
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    constructor(name, grade) {
        super(name);
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    sayHello() {
        console.log(`Hi, I'm a studend and my name is ` + this.name);
    }
}

let b = new Student("Some guy", 5);

b.sayHelloAndBye();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: However, if that’s the desired behavior a cleaner approach might be to put the logic into a new method that’s not supposed to be overwritten. I.e. `_sayHello() {...} sayHello() { this._sayHello();} sayHelloAndBy() { this._sayHello();...}` (or simply define a function outside the class and call that one).